# Return all duplicate pairs and their indexes in an integer array

Tags: c#, arrays, list, dictionary

Does someone know of a sleek elegant and optimised O(n) soln for retrieving the pairs and indexes for integer array. ex -

```
int[] array = { 2, 3, 2, 4, 2, 3, 5}
```

it needs to return something like -

```
{0,2}, {0,4}, {2,4}  // For pairs of 2
{1,5} // For pairs of 3
```

Looking for `O(n)` and not using `O(n²)` which can easily be done using 2 for loops.

Comment: Sounds impossible to me. Consider an array of length N, where all elements are the same. You'd have to emit O(n^2) elements... that's going to be hard to do in O(n) time.

Comment: Right..  was thinking of using a dictionary to hold the value and the last relevant position but that would give me only pairs of current and last relevant position.... loses context of the previous positions... 

example : returns {0,2}, {2,4} // for pairs of 2  , and {1,5} for pairs of 3

Comment: but the above will fail to return {0,2} using dictionary - (also that dict keys need to be unique.. so it can store only the integer(key) with last relevant pos (value)

Comment: I don't see how a proposed implementation is relevant here - you're still talking about generating O(n^2) elements in O(n) time...

Comment: Yea did not realise that.. :) . Jon - do you think the *elegant* soln then is to use nested for loops?

Comment: Well that would certainly be simple, using `yield`. But it's not a solution to your actual question. (An alternative would be to build a Lookup, which may be more efficient, but would still have the same worst case.)

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible because of the lower bound for sorting algorithms `Ω(n log n)`. If you could do the comparisons in `O(n)` you could implement `InsertionSort` in `O(n)` which is not possible.